# Access storage from another pallet

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet

I need to get the owner of an asset to filter extrinsic calls.
I tight couple the assets pallet to my pallet and I'm trying to access the Asset storage but getting the following error:

[image]

How can I solve this error or otherwise how can I get the owner of an specific asset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets pallet is a little bit special. They marked all storage as private.

And they provided a list of functions to access the storage.

Check if these functions could help you: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5b6519a7ff4a2d3cc424d78bc4830688f3b184c0/frame/assets/src/impl_fungibles.rs#L273-L291

Comment: It works. Thank you!
This is how I check for the owner using the functions that you post.

let asset_owner = <pallet_assets::Pallet<T>>::owner(asset_id);